# SQL Server 2014 Express Network Servers Tab Empty

Tags: sql-server, database, list, networking

When connecting to a database engine in SSMS, and using the "browse for more" option, the Network Servers tab list is empty.

I can type the server name manually in the Server Name field in the "Connect to Server" dialog window and connect just fine, but I can't browse for the list of available servers which is obviously more convenient.

The SQL Browser service is running on all the network servers that I want to connect to, which I verified by running "osql -L" from the command line. This in fact gives me the complete list of servers I should see in the network server tab of SSMS but don't.

Running the SQL Browser service on my local machine does not help, as of course that is just allowing my machine to broadcast its available services.

Any idea of what would be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
It seems like a bug in .NET Framework 4.6.

- **Uninstall** Microsoft **.NET Framework 4.6** (and all relevant component).

  - Visual Studio and Management Studio has been broken
- I **repair**ed Microsoft **Visual Studio** Premium 2013 with Update 3.

  - Control Panel --> Programs and functions --> MS VS P 2013 w U 3 --> Change --> **Repair**
- **Restart computer.**

Everything is fine and **Network Servers Tab** works.

Comment: This problem went away for me when I installed VS 2015 Update 1, which in turn updated .NET Framework 4.6

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

1. Go to **Connect Object Explorer**:

[image]

2. Fill in the **Server name**, **Login** and **Password** fields and click on **Options**:
   [image]
3. Go to **Connection Properties** tab, click on **Connection database**, **Browse server...**
   [image]
4. Click on **Yes**:
   [image]
5. It will show the databases.

Comment: The problem was not that the database list wouldn't populate for a given server, but that the server list itself would not populate